# Convert string of dictionary to list with removal of single quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have one string having dictionary, I want to convert it into a list, but unable to remove single quote while doing the same.

Can someone help me in figuring out what is missing here?

```
>>> a = '{"src_ports": [7] , "dst_ports": [8]}'
```

What I want is following:

```
[{"src_ports": [7] , "dst_ports": [8]}]
```

But what I get is following:

```
>>> a = [a]
>>> a
['{"src_ports": [7] , "dst_ports": [8]}']
```

Edited:
With ast, order of dictionary elements gets changed, I need to keep it intact.

```
>>> import ast
>>> b = [ast.literal_eval(a)]
>>> b
[{'dst_ports': [8], 'src_ports': [7]}]
```

Comment: `import json;  [json.loads(a)]`

Comment: Is it possible to do it without importing any extra modules?

Comment: Why do you have `a` to be a string originally if you are just going to make it not a string when putting it in the list. Why not make it a dictionary from the start?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a method to preserve order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `ast.literal_eval`

```
>>> import ast
>>> [ast.literal_eval(a)]
[{'src_ports': [7], 'dst_ports': [8]}]
```

---

#### `json.loads`

(Preserves order.)

```
>>> import collections
>>> import json
>>> [json.loads(a, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)]
[OrderedDict([('src_ports', [7]), ('dst_ports', [8])])]
```

Note that an `OrderedDict` is still a dictionary, so you can access its elements the same way you would a normal one.

Comment: @wim, did you delete my `eval` answer on purpose?

Comment: Yes, it was either that or a downvote.  Roll-back if you prefer the downvote.

Comment: @wim Well, not that it matters, but the OP wanted a method that didn't involve imports.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ast.literal_eval()` function as a safer `eval()` for that:

```
import ast

a = '{"src_ports": [7] , "dst_ports": [8]}'

b = [ast.literal_eval(a)]
# [{'dst_ports': [8], 'src_ports': [7]}]
```

**UPDATE** - Provided your structure remains the same, you can use the `json` module in combination with `collections.OrderedDict` if you want to preserve the order. Keep in mind that both Python `dict` and JSON are, generally, unordered structures:

```
import json
import collections

a = '{"src_ports": [7] , "dst_ports": [8]}'

b = json.loads(a, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
```

But if you print it out it you'll get something like `OrderedDict([(u'src_ports', [7]), (u'dst_ports', [8])])` however your order will be preserved, for example if you're serializing it later or loop through it.

Comment: @ zwer, I tried it, it changes the order of dictionary elements, is there anyway to preserve the same order in dictionary?

Comment: @Sweety there is no implicit order to dictionaries in pythons below 3.6. If you want, I recommend you use `collections.OrderedDict`, that preserves the order.

Comment: I am getting like this:`[OrderedDict([(u'src_ports', [7]), (u'dst_ports', [8])])]`, but this won't work for me as I need dictionary in exact same format just with removal of single quotes.

Comment: @Sweety - what do you want to do with the dictionary? You want it as a string?

Comment: I need to use this list with dictionary in further operations: `[{"src_ports": [7] , "dst_ports": [8]}]`

Comment: @Sweety - and you can use the `OrderedDict` instance in place of a regular `dict` just as fine - what does it matter how it prints out as a string?

Comment: @Sweety you should switch to python3.6. Please understand _there is no way_ to preserve the order of a vanilla dictionary.